# Linux script doesn't work

Tags: linux

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# script.sh

awk -F: '{if ($3 > 500) {print $3}}' /etc/passwd
awk -F: '{if ($3 > 500) {
if (size = "$(du -s /home/$1)" > 10000) {
mkdir /home/copy/R$1
cp /home/$1 /home/copy/R$1
}
}}' /etc/passwd
```

The first awk prints all the users with the UID above 500. The second awk should create the directory /home/copy/Ruser, and copy all the files of the user directory in it, when the size of the user directory is above 10000, but it doesn't do anything, and there's no error when I run the script.

Comment: Please elaborate on the title.

Comment: In awk, `'{if ($3 > 500) {print $3}}'` is much better written `$3 > 500 { print $3 }`

Answer (score 1):

`$( du -s )` is a shell syntax, not awk syntax. The following assigns the size of the home directory to `size` in gawk:

```
"du -s "$6" | cut -f1"  | getline size
if (size > 10000) {
    ...
```

Comment: So now I have this code:
`awk -F: '{if ($3 > 500) {print $3}}' /etc/passwd
awk -F: '{if ($3 > 500) {
"du -s "$6" | cut -f1" | getline size
if (size > 10000) {
mkdir /home/copy/R$1
cp $6 /home/copy/R$1
}
}}' /etc/passwd`
But it gives me the error "|" unexpected

Comment: What awk version do you run?

Answer (score 0):

Using awk for this is probably more trouble than it's worth:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=: read user passwd uid gid info dir shell; do
  test $uid -gt 500 2> /dev/null || continue  # Skip if uid too low
  size="$(du -s $dir)"
  if test "$size" -gt 10000; then
    mkdir /home/copy/R$user
    cp /home/$1 /home/copy/R$user  # This probably won't work!
  fi
done < /etc/passwd
```